# HTML5 video autoplay on mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

I am aware thate there are plenty of same questions available with accepted answers.

There is a wide saying that autoplay feature is supported on android chrome 53+. But it doesn't look so.

Currently on (Android Mobile)google chrome version 63,65 (these are the versions which I tested) **is not supporting autoplay**.(*But its supporting in firefox android*)

Just check this [link](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/muted-autoplay/index.html) from google developers on your android mobile chrome.

I also tried to play with scripts

```
var video_tag = document.getElementById('background-video');
video_tag.play();
```

Is there any other solutions or work around to **autoplay muted videos** on Android chrome?

**EDIT:**
Based on a [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#best-practices), I tried the option using promises return from play().

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();
if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
      alert("Autoplay started!");
  }).catch(error => {
      alert("Autoplay was prevented.");
      alert(error);
  });
}
```

I got the alert message.

***Autoplay was prevented.
Not Allowed-Error():play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.***

Does it give a conclusion that still in chrome (65) the autoplay is not supported even it is muted?

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: Is there any other solutions or work around to autoplay videos on Android chrome?

Comment: Yeah muted read this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Comment: But did you check this link, it contains both muted and non-muted versions none of them are playing.
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/muted-autoplay/index.html